# I'm unable to create NuGut Package. How to solve?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I'm unable to create nuget package, due I think to a lack of write permissions.

The path is the result of the Click Once installation.

How can I solve this?

Error:

---

### NuGet Package Explorer

Unable to generate a temporary class (result=1).

error CS0016: Could not write to output file 'c:\Users\Adam Speight\AppData\Local\Temp\0c2jg3wu.dll' -- 'Access is denied. '

---

### OK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange. Have you checked the folder exists, and the permissions on it? You could try temporarily granting Everyone write access on the folder to see if that helps.

Also check the disk isn't full, or the folder full of filenames generated by GetTempFile() - not sure what that does if it generates a random filename that already exists.

Comment: After clearing out the temp folder (>40,000 items and >2Gb) it seems to work now.